# Exponentially Correlated Draws From Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability, algorithms, random, correlation, gamma-distribution

This is more about algorithms than math.

I want to generate a series of random numbers corresponding to a given distribution, but in such a way that each draw is correlated to the previous according to some relation.

Suppose I have a correlation $f =e^{-\lambda\Delta t}$ and a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. I know that the following algorithm will give me exponentially correlated draws from the Gaussian distribution (algorithm modified from [here](https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/corr_gaussian_random.pdf)):

$f = e^{-\lambda \Delta t}$
$r_0 = \mu$

for $n > 0$ :
$\hspace{1cm} g_n = \sigma \times randn()$
$\hspace{1cm} r_n = f \times (r_{n-1} - \mu) + \sqrt{1 - f^2}\times g_n + \mu$

An example can be seen in this figure: [image: in this figure].

Here, $\lambda=0.1$, $\mu=10$, and $\sigma=4$.
I'm plotting with two different series, each with a different $\Delta t$.

As can be seen here, the resultant series of draws (after enough samples) is approximately Gaussian with the same $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

[image: in this figure]

How can I achieve this same effect with a gamma distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

After some testing, I found that my original answer did not work well for $\rho \le 0.02$ or $\rho \ge 0.98$, so I did some digging and found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236953720_Some_autoregressive_models_for_point_processes).

Using eqn(2.1) and eqn(4.3), I get very good results for all $\rho$.

Like below, a random draw, $r_t$ can be calculated as $r_t = \rho \times r_{t-1} + \zeta_t$, where $\rho$ is a correlation factor and $0 < \rho < 1$.

Again assuming a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $\alpha$ and rate parameter $\beta$, and noting that $Po(\lambda)$ is a draw from the Poisson distribution, apply the following:

$N = Po(\alpha\times \log{\frac{1}{\rho}})$

$\zeta_t = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\rho^{U_n}Y_n$

where $U_n$ is an independent draw from the uniform distribution and $Y_n$ is an independent draw from the exponential distribution with parameter $\beta$

Edge cases:

if $\rho=0$, then $r_t = Ga(\alpha, \beta)$

If $\rho=1$, $r_t=r_{t-1}$

---

A coworker of mine was able to solve this problem, so I'm posting her solution here for completeness:

The solution to this problem is a stationary Gamma process; in particular an auto-regressive AR(1) process. The following algorithm comes from:

*Walker, Stephen G.*, [**A note on the innovation distribution of a gamma distributed autoregressive process**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/1467-9469.00208), Scand. J. Stat. 27, No.3, 575-576 (2000). [ZBL0976.62091](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0976.62091).

However, since that is behind a paywall, the algorithm is also presented [here (section 2.1)](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring16/sta961/lec/6gam.pdf).

To summarize:

Assume a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $\alpha$ and rate parameter $\beta$ s.t. $\alpha,\beta > 0$. Assume each draw is correlated to the previous according to $\rho$ where $0 < \rho <1$.

A random draw, $r_t$ can be calculated as $r_t = \rho \times r_{t-1} + \zeta_t$

$\zeta_t$ can be calculated from the following, noting that $Ga(\alpha,\beta)$ is a random draw from the Gamma distribution and $Po(\lambda)$ is a random draw from the Poisson distribution:

$\lambda_t = Ga(\alpha,1)$

$N_t = Po(\frac{1-\rho}{\rho} \times \lambda_t)$

$\zeta_t = Ga(N_t, \frac{\beta}{\rho})$

An example can be seen here ($\alpha = 4, \beta = \frac{2}{3}$):
[image: line plot]

The resultant distribution (after a sufficient number of draws) is a Gamma distribution with approximately the same $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as the original distribution:
[image: histogram]

One final note: it's possible for $N_t=0$, in which case $\zeta_t = 0$